# When I use shutil.move(), it always seems to leave one (or more) behind. Why is this?

Tags: python, operating-system, move, file-handling, shutil

I have a program which is supposed to automate the creation of 'x' many files, and then move them all into 'x' many folders, however when I run it, it always seems to leave one behind, while all the rest are moved into their respective folders. Does anyone have any idea why this is?

Code:

```
import os
import shutil

for i in range(1, 11):
    sesame = open("Automated File 0{}.txt".format(i), 'w')
    sesame.write("Placeholder text")
    sesame.close()

class Automate():
    def createFolders():
        for i in range(1, 11):
            os.mkdir("Automated Folder 0{}".format(i))

    def moveFileToFolder():
        source = os.getcwd()
        file = os.listdir()

        for i in range(1, 11):
            if file[i].endswith(".txt"):
                shutil.move("Automated File 0{}.txt".format(i), "Automated Folder 0{}".format(i))

Automate.createFolders()
Automate.moveFileToFolder()
```

Comment: What's the point of `if file[i].endswith(".txt"):`? Why are you checking the file extension of a random file? You have no idea which file `file[i]` refers to.

Comment: Python is one-based. In `moveFiletoFolder`, use `i-1` when getting a name from `file`.

Comment: @zondo Thank you! I fiddled out with subtracting 1 and 2 from 'i' and it seems to work now.